# How to call Handlebar helper function from javascript?

Tags: handlebars.js

I am new to Handlebar & have few questions.
Please help on the same.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('formatNumber', function(options) {
  return "111";
});
```

How to call the above helper function from javascript ?
i.e. I pass a string & the function returns 111.

Answer (score 0):

In your handlebars template, `{{formatNumber}}` will output the result.

You can pass in a variable like this: `{{formatNumber 123}}`

Comment: I agree with you .. but I wanted to know how to call from javascript not from template